# How to replace the backward slash from string?

Tags: javascript

What is wrong with the following code?

Expected output : **substr1@substr2@substr3**

```js
var str = "substr1\substr2\substr3" 
// it works if I use the double slash "\\" in thestring but not with single.
console.log(str.replace(/\\/g, "@"));
```

Comment: You have to escape ` \ ` character in the string. Now it treats them as ` \s `.

Comment: The backslash (`\ `) is the escape character both in strings and in regular expressions. To represent itself it must be escaped: `\\ `. Read more about [strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) and [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) in JavaScript.

Comment: @AycanYaşıt : Thanks, but what should I do if I got string in above format?

Comment: you can use String.raw. This will work
    `var str = String.raw\`substr1\sustr2\substr3\`;
    console.log(str.replace(/\\/g, "@"));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your initial string itself do not have a backslash. To verify check the snippet below:

```js
var str = "substr1\sustr2\substr3" 
console.log(str);
```

The actual output you expect can be obtain by first escaping the backslash and then replacing it with `@`:

```js
var str = "substr1\\sustr2\\substr3" 
console.log(str.replace(/\\/g, "@"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I could do this, but what should I do if I have the input with a single "\"?

Comment: From where do you get the input with single slash? from your backend? Then make it to return double slash instead.

Comment: @NitinDhomse — You should correct the error *in your source code* by adding the additional slashes.

Comment: Or is there any pattern of the string that are separated by backslash? We can use regex to match that pattern and add `@` in between the string.

Comment: Thanks Ankit. will update my input  with a "\\"

Comment: Sure @NitinDhomse that will be lot easier for you and you can use the same code you have added in the question.